# Distribution of files by folder from the specified path in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have csv file, which indicates paths to the jpg files in their folders. The columns indicate names of the folders in which jpg must be copied, and in rows there are paths to the jpg in their original folder (from which it must be copied). Sharing the example by dput()

```
    mydata=structure(list(x1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    .Label = c("", "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\17992279.png", "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44245909_10_173_201907311705.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44253326_03_61_201907311507.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44249755_10_191_201907311444.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44253009_10_935_201907311358.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44254483_01_241_201907311457.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44537611_10_71_201908281506.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44548452_10_973_201908291551.jpg"), 

    class = "factor"), x2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    .Label = c("", "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44243943_10_916_201907311338.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44245909_10_173_201907311705.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44299011_10_52_201908281735.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44305733_10_845_201908261634.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44249755_10_191_201907311444.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44254483_01_241_201907311457.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44537550_10_155_201908310857.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\DKRBP18729589_08_881_201907311205.jpg"), 

    class = "factor"), x3 = structure(1:11, .Label = c("C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44243943_10_916_201907311338.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44245909_10_173_201907311705.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44265269_10_52_201908280944.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44299011_10_52_201908281735.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44305733_10_845_201908261634.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCI44540448_10_973_201908291524.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44249755_10_191_201907311444.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44254483_01_241_201907311457.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44537550_10_155_201908310857.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\CCSRBP44537577_10_890_201908271624.jpg", 
    "C:\\Users\\OCR\\Downloads\\OCR pass 2\\input\\DKRBP18729589_08_881_201907311205.jpg"), 
    class = "factor")), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -11L))
```

So, all the jpg file paths which are indicated in `x1` column must be copied to `C:\\X1\`
and  all jpg files paths which are indicated in `x2` column must be copied to `C:\\X2\`.

All jpg files paths which are indicated in `x3` column must be copied to `C:\\X3\`.

How to do it, via R?

Comment: See `?file.copy` to copy a file, `basename` to extract the base name (without the directory path) of a file, `paste` to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max,

it looks like, that when you read in your csv, you didn't put the option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, which leads to problems with the functions after.

You can convert `x1` etc through

```r
mydata=mydata %>% mutate_all(na_if,"") #sets the empty entries to NA
mydata=lapply(mydata, as.character) #sets all to character
mydata=lapply(mydata, na.exclude) #removes the NAs, empty elements would throw errors.

file.copy(from=mydata$x1,to=file.path("C:/X1",basename(mydata$x1)))}) #copies for the first "column".
```

I never do things like copying with `lapply`, because if one does it wrong it can get messy. Depending on how big you data frame is, you could try to do that too.
But I recommend to just rewrite the last line, which will also give you more control on where files are going.

```r
file.copy(from=mydata$x2,to=file.path("C:/X2",basename(mydata$x2)))})
file.copy(from=mydata$x3,to=file.path("C:/X3",basename(mydata$x3)))})
```

Note: in R it's far more convenient to use `/` as separators in file paths, this also works on windows.